# AutoHotkey: How can I paste text into this particular textbox?

Tags: autohotkey

Using AutoHotkey, I have a very tiny script to write text:

```
^m::
     SendInput Foo
Return
```

This works in most places like Notepad and chrome. However, it doesn't work for a particular program I am using. The program has a simple textbox which I can type text into. The program is called TextExpander. I am making sure the cursor is located in the textbox. For some reason, I can't get auto-hotkey to type text into it.

Any help? Tips?

Comment: Try other [Send*](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) commands like SendPlay.

Comment: Have you tried if you can paste text into TextExpander?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [`ControlSetText`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSetText.htm). Use WindowSpy to check the control name. If it has one, you can use that to set the text.

Alternately, make sure you're trying [`SendInput`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)/[`SendEvent`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendEvent)/[`SendPlay`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail).

If you have a way to reliably focus the box you're trying to enter text to, you can put your variable onto [`Clipboard`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm) and send paste via Ctrl+V `SendInput, ^v`.